# Validation error for one to one relationship in django modelfrom

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 2 models which are related to each other using One to One Relation. How can i display the validation error if object of one model is already related to another.

Suppose i have 2 models

```
   Class Place(models.Model):
        field1 = CharField()
        field2 = CharField()

   Class Restaurant(models.Model):
       related_field = OneToOneField(Place)
       field3 = CharField()
```

In my case **For one place one Restaurant**. **If user submits new Restaurant for the same place, then a validation should raise**

If Restaurant object already attached to Place object, so for second Restaurant for same Place object i want to display validation

In admin we usually see this message "**Restaurent with this Place already exists.**" But how can i achieve the same this using modelform with generic views

```
 class RestaurantCreateView(CreateView):
       form_class = RestaurantForm
       template_name = 'restaurant_create.html'

       def get_success_url(self):
           return reverse_lazy('restuarants', args=[self.object.id])

       def get_place(self, **kwargs):
           id = self.kwargs['pk']
           place = Place.objects.get(id=id)
           return place 

       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
           context = super(RestaurantCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
           place = self.get_place()
           context['place'] = place
           return context

       def form_valid(self, form):
          self.object = form.save(commit=False)
          place = self.get_place()
          self.object.place = place
          self.object.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

How can perform One To One relation validation in class based generic views?

Comment: Why would you want a OneToOneField here? That means publishers can only have one book, which seems very strange.

Comment: those are not my exact models.. Just for example i written like that

Comment: Well, please post something that actually shows what you want to do. Your mention of "publisher for this book", and your comment to Yuji, implies that you actually want to use a ForeignKey.

Comment: @Daniel: I updated the question, where i want one restaurant for one place, for the same place another restaurant should not be exist

Comment: @SahilM then my code answers your question

Comment: @YujiTomita : I'm not exposing the related_field in form for user to allow to change. So if i use cleaned_data.get('related_field'), will get None always.

Comment: @SahilM, well get however the user submits that related_field, query the model to get the object, then do the same. Somehow, a user ultimately selects a `Place` (or this validation wouldn't exist at all).

Comment: @Yuji: User will not selects a place. I have detail page for place object, in same page i provided link to create restaurant, which will take place id as url argument. Here user will not select place. In my question just see the class based generic view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you need to pass the `Place` object into your `Restaurant` form. The form validation has no access to these things defined in the view unless you explicitly pass it that data.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Restaurant

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.place = kwargs.pop('place', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs

    def clean_related_field(self):
        place = self.place
        try:
            place.restaurant
        except Restaurant.DoesNotExist:
            return place
        raise forms.ValidationError("Restaurant already exists for that book")


class MyView(...):
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MyView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['place'] = Place.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return kwargs

{% if form.related_field.errors %}.........{% endif %}
```

Another approach is to fake validation in form_valid() and set the errors dict, and return the response. This method may be preferable since it's much more contained. Also especially if you are not using the form field anyways, you might as well add an error flag to the context.

```
class MyView():
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if Restaurant.objects.filter(related_field=self.get_place()):
            ctx = self.get_context_data(form=form)
            ctx['massive_error'] = True
            return self.render_to_response(ctx)
```